# Is a file's 'Last modify' information correct after killing its process?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-xp, kill-process

Does Windows XP guarantee that a file's 'last modify' information (which can be read with _stat64) is correct, even if the process that created it (and left it open) was killed with the task manager, etc' ?  (not including pulling out the power cord)

From an experiment it looks like it closes the file upon killing, and sets the 'last modify' to that moment, but would like to be sure about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the process terminates shouldn't have any bearing on this kind of things, since, however a process terminates, the kernel handles (including those to files) are closed automatically, so the normal operations associated with closing file handles (including updating last modify time) should be performed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so (from user mode perspective) there can't be "open files" without the process that opened them being exist?